# Hide Text Value of HTML Input box when Toggle/Selected

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replicate the effect of **[THIS](https://ueno.co/contact/)** contact form where if the user clicks or selected the input text area, the value will disappear.

[Fiddle here!!!](https://jsfiddle.net/g9nkbcvz/)

```js
function hidetext() {
  var x = document.getElementById("carea");
  if (x.value.display === "none") {
    x.value.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.value.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input onclick="hidetext()" type="text" name="your-name" value="What's your name?" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required name" id="carea" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">

<input onclick="hidetext()" type="email" name="your-email" value="Your fancy email address?" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email email" id="carea" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">

<input onclick="hidetext()" type="tel" name="tel-818" value="Your mobile phone number?" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel mob" id="carea" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">

<input onclick="hidetext()" type="text" name="text-510" value="Tell us about your project" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required msg" id="carea" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

Comment: Are you looking for a `placeholder`??

Comment: Have a look at [placeholders](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

Comment: Suggest you start with some HTML basics, before you try your hand at scripting. IDs _must_ be unique within the scope on an HTML document.

Comment: Also IDs need to be unique

Comment: The site you mention simply changes the opacity of the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Googled that this can be achieved using CSS.

```
input:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use the "placeholder" attribute:

```js
document.querySelector('input').onfocus = function() {
 var ph = this.getAttribute('placeholder');
 if(!ph) return;
 this.setAttribute('placeholder', '');
 this.setAttribute('data-placeholder', ph);
}

document.querySelector('input').onblur = function() {
 var ph = this.getAttribute('data-placeholder'),
     val = this.value;
 if(!ph || val) return;
 this.setAttribute('placeholder', ph);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="What's your name?" >
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm going after the hide of the value text. placeholder is different. But thanks for taking the time to answer and giving the option.

Comment: correctamundo! I added the necessary JavaScript. But placeholder is definitely the way to go to be semantically correct.

Comment: fyi, this is not how you use the `placeholder` attribute. Having the JS event handlers defeats the purpose of the `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: I agree, but JS is needed to clear the placeholder from the input on focus (as this requested behaviour is not standard). Doing this with the value attribute might cause issues on submitting the form when no input was given, let alone form validation

Comment: @RenaudC. the placeholder disappears when the user types, you don't need to clear it, at all

Comment: i know, but the question was to clear the placeholder on focus (without having to type anything)